# Is it possible to use async / await in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I started programming in React Native, and I got used to use the syntax:

```
async myFunction(){
    ...
    return await otherFunction();
}
```

But I don't know how to make it compatible with React JS and React Native in a shared package. How can I accomplish this so that it works in both platforms?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at AsyncStorage in react native official documents? (edit: just noticed this is asked months ago)

Comment: @EnieJakiro I don't know how AsyncStorage is related to the question. I do use AsyncStorage but only for React Native.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

React Native ships with Babel and some Babel presets, whereas React on the web is just React related code.

If you want to use async/await on the web today you'll need Babel and the correct transforms: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/

or the stage-1 presets, which is fairly common in React apps today. http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer @azium. I installed both and after running "npm run dev" I get the error "Unexpected token" for the async function

Comment: You're going to have to show more about your project to diagnose.. can you post your package.json and webpack.config.js files?

Comment: At the end, transform-async-to-generator does work well for React, thanks @azium

Answer (score 49):

If you building using create-react-app it's been available since v0.2.3

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/releases/tag/v0.2.3

It can be used inside a Component like this

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { message: '' };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ message: 'loading...' });
    let d = await getData('/posts/1');
    this.setState({ message: d });
  }

  render() {
    let { message } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p className="App-intro">
          { message }
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

See:

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1024

Comment: That's a really good tip. I did not know of this way for building an app. Thank you!

Comment: Tim, whats the usage to async the componentDidMount method?

Comment: thanks, but it's not working with arrow functions. I use arrow function to avoid extra line of code for binding `this` in constructor. Any tip on how to make it compatible with arrow functions. I am using CRA

Comment: nvm i was writing `async somefunction = () => { }` instead of `somefunction = async () => { }`

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can use [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/).

Since version 2.1 it is possible to use `async/await` and directly [transpile to ES5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/11/08/typescript-2-1-rc-better-inference-async-functions-and-more/) (in other words have it run on ~all browsers)