# How can I call an ASYNC function inside of .map for populating a table in REACT?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, promise, array.prototype.map

I am trying to call an async function using .map() in REACT to populate table data cells. The async function is calling the backend of my application using data from the array that is being iterated through.

The function that is being called returns a number when called properly.
This is my first time posting a question so any help is great! If I need to add more information I will.

Thank you.

```
{tableInfo.map(info => (
      <tr>
        <td key={info.name}>{info.name}</td>
        <td key={info.price}>{info.price}</td>
        <td key={info.amount}>{info.amount}</td>
        <td>
          {async () => await fetchCurrentPrice.getPrice(info.name)}
        </td>
      </tr> ))}
```

Comment: Maybe this could help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357234/is-it-possible-to-use-async-await-in-react-js

Comment: Are you really trying to make one http request per row of your table? Don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`async` functions *always* return promises. You can't fetch data asynchronously during rendering.

You need a `useEffect` hook to run the function which gathers the data, and then a `useState` hook to store it, along with logic to show a loading state while you wait for it.

```
const MyRow = ({ info }) => {
   const [currentPrice, setCurrentPrice] = useState(null);

   useEffect(() => {
       fetchCurrentPrice.getPrice(info.name).then(setCurrentPrice);
   }, [info]);

   return <tr>
        <td key={info.name}>{info.name}</td>
        <td key={info.price}>{info.price}</td>
        <td key={info.amount}>{info.amount}</td>
        <td>{currentPrice ?? <Loading />}</td>
   </tr>

}
```

with

```
{tableInfo.map(info => <MyRow key={info.name} info={info} />)}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not aware that you couldn't fetch data asynchronously during rendering.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you again. I can't upvote because I am still too new, but this helped so much.

Comment: @Archer3127 — Glad it worked for you. You can't up vote yet, but you can [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to show that it solved your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use a separate component for the tr tag and call it within it.

```js
const Component = (props) => {
  const {info} = props
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // call your api and set it to state
  }, [])
  
  return <tr>
        <td key={info.name}>{info.name}</td>
        <td key={info.price}>{info.price}</td>
        <td key={info.amount}>{info.amount}</td>
        <td>
          {async () => await fetchCurrentPrice.getPrice(info.name)}
        </td>
      </tr>
}

{tableInfo.map(info => <Component info={info} />)}
```

Comment: `{async () => await fetchCurrentPrice.getPrice(info.name)}` is still going to spit a stringified promise object into the field.

Comment: Your live demo throws syntax errors too.

Comment: It's not demo, it's code sample.